# Global variable is smashed

Tags: c, stack, embedded, codewarrior, 68hc08

I have the next code:

```
#include <math.h>

int x;
float Temp = 0;

void main(){

x = 2;

for(;;){
   Temp=log(20);
}
}
```

I shortened my code to the important line. The problem I have is once x is declared as 2 and then I do log() function, this calculation alter to x variable and change it to a huge valour.

Codewarrior (the IDE I'm using to), says that Temp variable is in the location 0x0102 and x variable is in 0x0108.

I need x for a function in "MCUinit.h" so it's important that x variable isn't greater than 5, and codewarrior give like 5000 or even greater after doing log(whatever)

How could I do so that log() don't alter others variables?

thanks

Before doing log() function.
https://ibb.co/6ZHh6D0

After doing log() function.
https://ibb.co/Np99Sz4

Comment: What is your platform? `log()` doesn't alter anything. Please [edit] your question and show where __excatly__ `x` is changed. Also post a [mcve] and read this: [ask]

Comment: While shortening your code is a good thing, it still needs to be a [mre]

Comment: Change `Temp` to `double`, because that's what `log()` returns

Comment: double is not a solution =(

Comment: What happens if you remove `volatile`? And what is your platform?

Comment: nothing interesting. MCUinit doesn't take `x` correctly.

I'm editing the previous code simplier

Comment: platform?

I'm using codeWarrior Development Studio. The uController i'm working on is MC9S08QE32

Answer (score 2):

This is an obvious stack overflow. S08 is an incredibly resource-constrained 8 bit MCU. It is not a PC. It does not have a FPU. This means that you *cannot and should not use floating point arithmetic, ever*. Period. And avoid using 32 bit arithemtic in general.

What happens when you roll up math.h is that Codewarrior injects a bombastic software floating point lib, completely slaughtering all the available memory and CPU resources in the whole MCU, turning your program into a useless mess. One single `log` call was apparently enough to kill the stack. I'm not surprised, you have some 100-200 bytes of stack per default. And when that happens, the stack overflows into the `.data`/`.bss` memory areas where the variables `x` and `Temp` are stored, destroying it while writing gibberish in those areas.

If you actually *need* to use floating point calculations, then tough luck, you picked the wrong MCU. Should have picked a Cortex M4.

In addition, you should always place the stack so that it grows (it's a down-counting SP) into harmless memory areas, not into the `.data`/`.bss` sections. Why Codewarrior doesn't do this as default is very strange. Having the stack grow into the register map isn't ideal either, but in case you aren't using all the timer peripherals around 0x70 then it's at least a less bad scenario than corrupting all variables in the program.

Comment: maybe you are right, but I think this IDE does wierd thing =S.

If i calculate Temp = log(20); in which Temp is in location 0x102, How's possible that a variable in the location 0x0100 is also change?
even a variable in location 0x04f7. =S

Comment: @KotitoOtitok Just observe the stack in the debugger. What's the stack start address?

Comment: Of course weird things happen when the stack overflows.  It is your responsibility as the programmer to understand your target, and its limitations, and to avoid going outside these limitations.  If you are using a tiny brain-dead microcontroller like the S08, avoid floating point as much as possible.  And if you can't avoid it completely, at least avoid doubles and transcendental functions like "log".

Comment: @David No, trust me on this: you cannot use floating point _at all_ on S08QE32. It's simply too limited. It's bad enough to have Codewarrior link the floating point libs instead of the fixed point ones to kill off significant parts of the available RAM through .bss bloat. I know every little dirty detail of this tool chain since I have worked with S08 parts since they were new some 10 years ago and before that 68HC08.

Answer (score -2):

Somehow I came up with a possible solution. I guess it isn't the best solution due to my programming level but it works.

As my program executed line `Temp=log(20)` its outcome was a bit mess because it was changing too many valours in the RAM with some kind of variables inside, and then log() was giving me its own valour and trash, smashing from its position 0x0100 and further. So what I did was to change 'float Temp'  in ' float Temp[10] and I gathered the real valour and trash in that array. So I just had to take the interested valour.

Thanks for eveyone.
I'm still here to heard new suggestion, anyway.

Comment: When your stack overflows, you can no longer rely on your code doing anything sensible - _anything_ can happen.  If you think making an array to "catch the trash" is helpful, it is purely a matter of luck combined with a lack of proper testing to see what else has gone wrong.  Do _not_ treat it as a solution or workaround.